# Bundle install ignores build arguments

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.2.2 in docker along with the tk gem. I need to pass some build arguments to the tk gem so it will work under docker, but bundle install isn't passing them.

Here's a docker file to reproduce the problem:

```
# Dockerfile
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=20.04

FROM ubuntu:${UBUNTU_VERSION}

ARG RUBY_VERSION=2.2.2
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION=1.17.3
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG TIMEZONE=America/Vancouver

ENV TNS_ADMIN=/config \
    DISPLAY=:0 \
    NLS_LANG="American_America.UTF8" \
    TZ='' \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq upgrade &&\
    apt-get -qq install \
    wget tzdata less unzip tcsh make rlwrap build-essential graphviz \
    curl g++ gcc autoconf automake bison libc6-dev \
    libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev libtool \
    libyaml-dev make pkg-config zlib1g-dev libgmp-dev \
    libreadline-dev libssl-dev alien libaio1 pdftk tk-dev \
    software-properties-common
RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm && \
    apt-get -qq update 

COPY rvm-install.sh .
COPY Gemfile .
RUN apt-get install -qq rvm && \
    /bin/bash -l ./rvm-install.sh


CMD /bin/bash -l
```

The `rvm-install.sh` script installs rvm and calls bundle install.

```
#!/bin/bash
# rvm-install.sh
set -e  # exit on error

echo foo $RUBY_VERSION

rvm requirements
rvm install $RUBY_VERSION
rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Gemfile
gem install bundler -v "${BUNDLER_VERSION}"
bundle config build.tk --with-tcltkversion=8.6 \
    --with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
    --with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
    --enable-pthread

bundle install
```

Finally, the `Gemfile` with `tk` commented out.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'

gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.8.1'
# gem 'tk', '0.4.0'
```

That builds just fine, and I can run the image. However, when I try to add `tk` to the `Gemfile` and install it, it fails.

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it docker_test
root@96df1dc82650:/# echo "gem 'tk', '0.4.0'" >> Gemfile                                              
root@96df1dc82650:/# bundle install             
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Resolving dependencies...         
Using bundler 1.17.3                            
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0             
Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1                  
Fetching tk 0.4.0                                                                                    
Installing tk 0.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
                                                  
    current directory: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/tk-0.4.0/ext/tk
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0 -r ./siteconf20230218-152-vzqit6.rb extconf.rb --with-tcltkversion\=8.6\
--with-tcl-lib\=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu\ --with-tk-lib\=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu\ --with-tcl-include\=/usr/include/tcl8.6\ --with-tk-include\=/usr/include/tcl8.6\ --enable-pthread                     
[...]
Specified Tcl/Tk version is ["8.6 --with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --enable-pthread", "8.6 --with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --enable-pthread"]
[...]
An error occurred while installing tk (0.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.                          
Make sure that `gem install tk -v '0.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.                                                                                                      
                                                  
In Gemfile:                                                                                                                                                                                                
  tk                                                                                                                                                                                                       
root@96df1dc82650:/#
```

That looks like the arguments might be passed to the wrong step.

If I try installing with `gem install`, it works fine.

```
root@96df1dc82650:/# gem install tk -- --with-tcltkversion=8.6 --with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --enable-pthread
Building native extensions with: '--with-tcltkversion=8.6 --with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 --enable-pthread'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed tk-0.4.0
Parsing documentation for tk-0.4.0
Installing ri documentation for tk-0.4.0
Done installing documentation for tk after 8 seconds
1 gem installed
root@96df1dc82650:/#
```

So what `bundle config` setting should I use? The [bundle docs](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-config.1.html#BUILD-OPTIONS) have an example that looks just like mine.

> A very common example, the `mysql` gem, requires Snow Leopard users to pass configuration flags to `gem install` to specify where to find the `mysql_config` executable.
>
> ```
> gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
> ```
>
> Since the specific location of that executable can change from machine to machine, you can specify these flags on a per-machine basis.
>
> ```
> bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
> ```
>
> After running this command, every time bundler needs to install the `mysql` gem, it will pass along the flags you specified.

Why doesn't that work for `tk`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a [known bug in bundler](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/6940), and should be fixed in bundler v2.1.0. I can't upgrade that far, so I'm going to call `gem install` instead of adding `tk` to the `Gemfile`.